# Given a list of subsrings and a string, print out the item in the list if it is a substring

Tags: java, string, algorithm

Given a list of subsrings and a string, print out the item in the list if it is a substring.

What's the most efficient way to do this without using any substring methods?

**Example:**

Input: `["cat", "dog", "foo", "foopoo", "foopo", "nope", "dogf"]`

Output: `"catdogfoopoo"`

**Explanation:**

"c" is in the map at index 0.

Loop through the length of "cat" and compare if its the same as from 0 to the length of "cat"

If yes, print.

**My idea:**

So my idea so far is that you would loop through the string given and map each character to an arraylist of indices

<(c, [0]), (a, [1]), (r, [2]), (d, [3]), (o, [4,7,8,10,11]), (g, [5]), (f, [6]), (p, [4])>

and then you loop through the list of substrings.

```
for (int x = 0; x < list.length; x++) {
    String s = list.get(x);
    if (s.get(s.charAt(0)) != null)
         //loop through, comparing from whether the word is in the string
```

but this doesn't take advantage of the fact that if "foo" was already found to be a substring, it should be easy to check if "foopoo" is a substring (without looping through foo already)

I'm a bit stuck there because I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do this. Without using "contains" or whatnot (which is NOT more efficient)

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit about how you actually got to your output for your example?

Comment: If you aint allowed to use contains then mention it. Badly specified question, down vote.

Comment: I changed `cardogfoopoo` to `catdogfoopoo`, I assume the `r` was just a typing error.

Comment: The question you are asking is not trivial.  When you put the constraint of "most efficient" on there, you open up a whole plethora of questions:  Most in efficient time or space (memory) or lines of code?  On average, worst case, best case?  e.g. Sorting could give you a better time on average but be no better than not sorting for all real inputs, and then you may have created a huge maintenance nightmare of code that doesn't provide any real benefit.  Good luck.

Comment: @MadConan Most efficient in time! Although a combination of time and space would be great. I'm practicing interview questions and I thought of this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++){
   if(input.contains(array[i])){
       System.out.println(array[i]);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Without using .contains either. looking for the algorithm

Comment: You didn't say "not using contains."  If you can't define the problem scope correctly, don't punish people for attempting to help you.

Comment: Never, ever, ever downvote someone when they provide a solution to your original question. Not MadConans fault you did not specify your question well enough.

Comment: My bad, assumed it was you.

Comment: Although I'm not sure using "contains" would be more efficient - how does "contains" work in java?

Comment: It is most likely not the most efficient from a pure processing standpoint but it is from lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a solution that covers this issue.

```
String text = "cardogfoopoo";
for (int x = 0; x < list.length; x++) {
    if(text.containts(list[x])
         System.out.println(list[x] + " is a substring!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should sort the substrings and generate a data structure similar to this (it is an array of linked lists):

```
[0] cat
[1] dog -> f
[2] foo -> po -> o
[3] nope
```

In this structure you can find the substrings "dog" and "dogf", as well as "foo", "foopo" and "foopoo". It is similar to searching in a dictionary.

You start at index 0 of your "catdogfoopoo" string, and starts to search through the dictionary, i.e. look for an entry which starts with 'c'. You find out that index 0 of the structure contains 'c', so you decide to walk through its length. So you take the entry length (3 characters) and see if the three characters starting at index 0 are equal to it (it's a string comparison, it can't be helped). They are, so you print "cat" because you found a whole entry that is contained in your string.

Next index is 3 i.e. character 'd', and you are at the first entry of position [0] of the dictionary. There are no further entries in this position so you must look for a different entry starting with 'd' so you find "dog" as the first entry of position [1]. You compare this entry (which is made out of three characters) with the characters in the string starting at index 4 and you find they are equal, so you print "dog". Next index is 6 and you compare it the next entry which is "f" and you find they are equal so you print "dogf".

And so on until you print "foo", "foopo" and "foopoo".

Hope it is clear. If you find it useful I can provide the details on how I created the structure.

Comment: How did you generate this/what was the logic behind it?